# Calling PHP wrapper on client side

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, cordova

I´m currently working on a school project, where we are using Apache cordova (HTML, CSS and JS side) and currently our school has a server, where our .php file is located.

In our project, (one of the HTML files) we use API key and an domain address, that we want to get rid off from source code (so other students cant see it). What would be easiest way to execute this?

We´ve been thinking following;

We use the php-file as a wrapper with the following code;

IE.

```
<?php
function getJson($data){

    $decoded = json_decode($data);
    if (isset($decoded)){

        // Toteutusten haku
        $url = "URL THAT WE DONT WANT TO BE SEEN";
        $apiKey = "API KEY GOES HERE";

        // curl
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        // curl_exec returnsanswer (not boolean)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Asets api key, ":"
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $apiKey.":");

        // Setting message - JSON
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

        // Sets false if necessary
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        // Sends request
        $responseJson = curl_exec($ch);
        return $responseJson;
        curl_close($ch); //close session
    **}
}
?>
```

And in HTML file we have code snippets that looks like following;

```
// B building rooms
            if (buildingcode.startsWith("B", 5)) {
                var requestB = new XMLHttpRequest();
                requestB.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (requestB.readyState === 4) {
                        if (requestB.status === 200) {
                            try {
                                var jsonB = JSON.parse(requestB.responseText);
                                for (var fb = 0; fb < jsonB.resources.length; fb++) {
                                    var resB = jsonB.resources[fb];

                                    if (resB.type === "room") {
                                        if (bTilat.indexOf("code")) {
                                            bTilat.push(resB.code + resB.name.slice(resB.name.indexOf(' ('), 50));
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (e) {
                                console.log(e.message);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //console.log(bTilat);
                };
                requestB.open("GET", 'THIS PART HAS THE DOMAIN WE WANT TO HIDE', true, "THIS PART HAS THE API WE WANT TO HIDE", "");
                requestB.send(null);
            }
```

So my question is following; I guess we need to get rid off

```
requestB.open("GET", 'THIS PART HAS THE DOMAIN WE WANT TO HIDE', true, "THIS PART HAS THE API WE WANT TO HIDE", "");
                    requestB.send(null);
```

From html, but how do we request the code from wrapper?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: when you say you use php-file as a wrapper, it's not clear what it actually "wraps".. it is located server-side, isn't it? If it's meant to wrap your url and API code, you'll still need to have this php url in your code, which ends a bit the same, just more convoluted. The only solution i see actually is obfuscation. but one way or another, i will be possible to see this url, it will just be harder.

Comment: @Kaddath Yeah the wrapper is on server-side.

Comment: You can not really hide the domain at all, even if your JS code obfuscates it the request can easily be analysed with your browser or other other tools.. also the rest of the request is usually visible on the client itself, even if your use HTTPS.

Comment: @xander on Cordova it's harder than on a browser to monitor the requests, but yes, with other tools it may be possible (if you know some i'd gladly like to know, as debugging requests is boring on Cordova). But at the end, of course, the domain will not be really hidden.

Comment: @xander Do you have any suggestions or methods to resolve this problem?

Comment: @Cod3r-b0ss it's more a pure logic question, somehow, your code needs to know who to contact, you can add complexity layers to it, but never solve it completely.. if at least APKs were not simple zips.. sigh

Comment: you are absolutely on the right track with your code if your intention is to hide the URL for the API and the API key, thus concealing which service's api you are using and your api key. You want to have an internal URL where your php code contacts the api and you get the result from there. You need AJAX. jQuery has nice ajax functions.